# implementing password hashing in iOS applications

Tags: ios, hash

I am trying to implement password hashing in my iPad application.I found [secure salted password hashing](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm) link which is having sample codes of java, .net ,etc but not ios. Can anybody help me to found a solution in the same way how they are doing...

Answer (score 1):

Use common crypto library for making md5 of your password.

```
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonDigest.h>
```

and then use.

```
- (NSString *) md5:(NSString *) input
{
    const char *cStr = [input UTF8String];
    unsigned char digest[CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    CC_MD5( cStr, strlen(cStr), digest ); // This is the md5 call

    NSMutableString *output = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH * 2];

    for(int i = 0; i < CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++)
        [output appendFormat:@"%02x", digest[i]];

    return  output; 
}
```

Comment: what about decription using md5 ?

Comment: md5 is not reversible. If you want to decrypt password then go for RSA algorithm. You can also use AES but it is not as secure as RSA.

Comment: @Earth MD5 is **not** encryption, it is one-way hashing. But do not use MD5, for hashing use a SHA-2 hash function, MD5 is just to weak. But if you are creating a key from a password then use PBKDF2.

Comment: @AshishP RSA is not more secure, it is an entirely different encryption scheme used for different purposes, mainly for PKI. The only thing insecure about AES is the same for RSA: choosing a weak key.

Answer (score 1):

Note that [MD5 is insecure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5#Security) and shouldn't be used for hashing sensitive information such as passwords. You should instead use SHA1 or SHA256 like this:

```
+ (NSData *)sha256:(NSData *)data {
    unsigned char hash[CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    if(CC_SHA256([data bytes], [data length], hash) ) {
        NSData *sha256 = [NSData dataWithBytes:hash length: CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];        
        return sha256;
    }
    return nil;
}
```